# Numpy slicing array memory consumption

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a big 2D numpy array with billions of rows and a few hundred columns, and I would like to select about 100 columns using `x[:, [0, 1, 3, 5, 11, ...]]` I thought it will only create a view of the original numpy array but in fact it is creating a copy of data along the process and blows up machine memory. Why does it need to consume memory in addition to the original data? And is there anyway to avoid doing that?

Comment: A `view` is a new array that uses the original `data-buffer` (1d version of the source array) and its own `shape` and `strides`.  That's possible with `basic indexing`, slices in all dimensions.  But you have a list for the columns.  It can't select an irregular pattern of columns with a slice.

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean if instead of using a list of column indices, I use a range, like x[:, 10:100], then there should be no additional memory consumption here?

Comment: I just give it a quick shot, it seems I can do things like [x:, 10:100] and [x:, 10:100:3] without creating additional copy, due to the reason it can use shape and strides to infer the position of elements from the original data, but it will create a copy of the data if I do x[:, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

Answer (score 0):

As the comments above stated, basic indexing only creates a view and thus avoids the additional memory.

If you still need the slice to be defined using a list of indices for the columns for ease of access to subparts later on, then I guess that you could create a wrapper class that processes the column slicing on the fly:

```
import numpy as np

class Slicer:
    def __init__(self, data, column_indices):
        self._data = data
        self._columns = column_indices

    def __str__(self):    # used here only for debug/demonstration
        return self._data[:, self._columns].__str__()

    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        #print(rows)
        return self._data[indices[0], self._columns[indices[1]]]

a = np.random.rand(3, 6)
print(a)

b = Slicer(a, [1, 2, 4])
print(b)

c = b[:2, :]
print(c)
```

```
[[0.51290284 0.63379959 0.87076258 0.55393205 0.06055949 0.89285849]
 [0.8581135  0.05557465 0.22056647 0.95438171 0.0444966  0.16140554]
 [0.55770268 0.88788224 0.06126918 0.59973579 0.37484009 0.14142807]]
[[0.63379959 0.87076258 0.06055949]
 [0.05557465 0.22056647 0.0444966 ]
 [0.88788224 0.06126918 0.37484009]]
[[0.63379959 0.87076258 0.06055949]
 [0.05557465 0.22056647 0.0444966 ]]
```